# How to use Data Blocks for building an Extent Tree?

Tags: tree, filesystems, ext4

I am building an extent-based File System for a school project.
I wanted to use an ext4-like design with its Extent Trees, but I don't understand how exactly the Extent Trees are built.

As far as I understood, there is one inode per one file and Extent Trees are made of one inode, multiple index nodes and multiple leaf nodes (the latter point to data blocks).

- Are index nodes and leaf nodes essentially also data blocks?
- Index node and inode are not the same, right?
- How should a data block be formatted to become an index node or a leaf node?

[Extent Tree Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I753b.png)